# How to get Stripe checkout to show a $249 CAD price with a 5% tax when the customer is in canada and $249 USD with no taxe in the rest of the world?

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I have a business located in Canada and there is a tax of 5% I want to charge with a price of 249 CAD. For the rest of the world, I want to set a price of 249 USD with no tax.
I've created multiple prices with different currencies like said [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/present-local-currencies#create-multi-currency-prices) but I just can't figure out how to pass multiple prices (stripe says you can pass them in the line options)! Also, I've created a tax for the Canada region, how can I activate it when the user selects "Canada" in the checkout session?

```
var options = new SessionCreateOptions
    {
        AutomaticTax = new SessionAutomaticTaxOptions { Enabled = true },
        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
        {
            new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                
                Price = "price_idUS",
                Quantity = 1,
            },
        },
        Mode = "payment",
        SuccessUrl = domain + "/payment/success",
        CancelUrl = domain + "/payment/cancel",
        ClientReferenceId = userId,
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create multiple Price objects. You just need to create one Price object (a multi-currency Price), specifying 249 CAD and 249 USD [within currency_options](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-currency_options). Then, you can [pass in that Price ID when you create the Checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price) (you only need 1 line item). If you've already configured a 5% tax with Stripe Tax for Canada, then that should just work assuming you [pass tax_behavior](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-currency_options-tax_behavior) on the Price object for the Canadian currency option. If you don't need to collect a tax outside of Canada, then your [Stripe Tax registrations](https://stripe.com/docs/tax/set-up#add-registrations) should reflect that. Also, if you want all non-Canadian customers to pay in USD, you can [set the default currency on the Price object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-currency) to USD.

Comment: Thank you! I've created one price with different prices! But it remains on the default USD price when I select Canada for the "Country or Region" dropdown. Is that how stripe intends it to work? Do I need to determine the user's country before I create the checkout session?

Comment: I mean a price where usd is the default and cad is another currency option

Comment: @GeorgK. Local presentment is mostly based on IP address; read more about this here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/present-local-currencies#checkout-experience. If you want to test out presentment in different countries see this section: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/present-local-currencies#test-currency-presentment